# "Incorrect number of dimensions" when exporting .txt file

Tags: r

I'm trying to export data from a `.xls` file by converting it into a `.txt` that contains data in triplicates with the first row and column containing names. I want to create another data frame (without the first row and column) in which I would have do the means of my triplicates.

I tried this :

```
fileavg <- readline(prompt="Add your .txt file")
data <- read.table(fileavg, header=FALSE)


a <- 2
b <- a + 2
var <- 0

l1 <- nrow(data) - 1
l2 <- ncol(data) - 1
l0 <- l1 / 3
avg <- 0


for (n in (1:l0)) {
  for (j in (2:(l2+1))) {
    for (i in (a:b)) {
      avg[n,(j-1)] <- avg[n,(j-1)] + data[i,j]
    }
    avg[n,(j-1)] <- avg[n,(j-1)] / 3
  }
  a <- a + 3
  b <- b + 3
}
```

for example, a typical .txt that I can use :

```
Well    t1  t2  t3  t4  t5  t6  t7  t8  t9  t10 t11 t12 t13 t14 t15 t16 t17 t18 t19
A1  0,53    0,35    0,51    0,69    1,01    1,01    1,34    1,51    2,31    3,14    5,85    6,19    9,7 10,41   12,57   14,34   15,96   18,53   22,18
A2  1,04    0,83    0,84    0,84    0,83    1,04    1,42    1,82    2,77    2,77    6,37    6,76    10,9    8,99    14,15   13,96   19,44   18,52   24,16
A3  1,08    0,9 0,9 0,9 0,73    0,73    1,91    1,74    3,85    3,68    6,32    5,82    10  9,68    14,61   13,09   20,21   21,27   27,06
A4  1,58    1,13    1,35    1,35    2,03    2,03    2,41    2,63    2,81    2,81    3,31    2,89    4,56    4,37    7,21    6,82    10,71   9,96    14,7
A5  0,58    0,39    0,6 0,6 0,78    0,98    1,54    1,35    2,88    3,06    4,23    3,87    8,98    11,44   16,83   15,68   23,15   21,1    28,05
A6  1,04    0,62    1,24    1,04    1,43    1,43    1,35    1,35    2,09    1,9 3,6 3,24    5,75    5,05    9,98    7,82    13,27   11,17   17,42
B1  0,87    0,87    0,91    0,91    2,17    5,07    11,54   21,65   40,25   57,63   83,22   90,98   96,24   97,98   99,06   99,19   99,72   100 56,28
B2  0,33    0,33    0,77    0,77    1,56    4,11    8,11    11,95   23,02   32,34   54,12   65,72   84,72   93,41   97,1    98,74   99,63   99,88   99,88
B3  1,57    1,4 1,45    1,29    2,78    4,1 8,41    13,04   21,66   25,25   43,06   52,69   68,83   77,72   91  94,37   98,37   99,32   99,87
B4  0,44    0,22    0,45    0,45    0,46    0,93    0,9 1,13    1,74    2,17    2,95    2,53    5,16    4,96    9,73    8,78    11,79   12,14   15,44
B5  0   0   0   0   0,22    0,89    3,13    3,55    5,5 6,92    10,13   10,71   18,28   17,73   27,62   27,8    36,12   37,65   44,08
B6  0   0   0,4 0,4 0,96    1,73    3,98    5,88    11,35   13,27   18,23   20,4    30,02   28,69   40,71   41,01   48,98   46,78   54,03
C1  1,25    1,08    0,93    0,74    0,92    0,73    3,55    2,66    6,17    7,89    13,27   11,73   22,78   18,79   34,71   30,86   44,79   38,08   23,95
C2  0,58    0,39    0,6 0,6 0,39    0,98    1,97    2,17    3,67    4,77    7,52    8,44    11,88   11,35   18,38   17,53   23,95   22,77   34,4
C3  0,91    0,54    1,06    0,89    1,73    2,25    2,39    3,08    4,82    5,95    9,86    9,86    16,85   13,9    23,94   17,72   30,19   23,91   38,07
C4  1,17    0,97    1,19    0,68    2,45    4,89    13,51   21,09   47,6    58,21   81,35   84,82   96,85   98,18   99,68   99,84   99,84   100 100
C5  0,57    0,57    1   0,83    4,56    16,45   48,05   68,08   92,87   95,69   99,2    99,36   100 100 100 99,69   100 100 100
C6  0   0   0,33    0   3,21    7,78    26,86   40,71   72,37   82,24   94,64   96,27   99,2    99,84   99,84   100 100 100 100
D1  4,86    10,44   30,43   52,31   80,4    89,13   96,37   98,33   99,73   99,86   99,87   100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
D2  5,14    15,83   38,47   55,48   82,25   89,72   97,39   98,62   99,87   99,87   100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
D3  3,32    9,56    26,45   45,21   76,14   85,92   96,57   97,89   100 100 100 100 100 100 100 99,75   100 100 100
D4  0,93    0,93    1,23    1,41    2,09    2,62    3,97    4,49    5,75    7   8,91    10,91   17  20,84   29,47   34,44   40,19   45,47   50,65
D5  0,85    0   1,23    1,38    1,67    2,12    2,93    4,78    6,97    8,4 10,6    13,29   18,49   22,99   27,94   33,17   42,24   47,03   53,63
D6  0,31    0,15    0,69    0,83    1,35    1,75    2,84    4,05    7,48    9   12,62   15,12   18,49   21,05   25,64   30,95   36,56   37,86   46,96
E1  0,68    1,19    1,47    1,8 4,46    7,6 16,41   21,32   40  48,7    65,99   70,92   83,14   83,81   93,23   93,39   98,06   98,06   99,36
E2  0,21    0,21    0,22    0,22    0,22    0,43    0,64    0,64    0,64    0,64    2,03    2,03    3,8 4   6,01    7,3 10,93   11,13   15,15
E3  0,65    0,98    2,37    2,84    10,14   17,55   31,81   41,27   57,75   62,81   75  77,63   87,15   88,65   95  95,83   98,04   98,04   98,28
E4  1,51    1,29    1,34    1,34    1,55    1,32    1,55    1,33    2,44    2,44    2,79    2,58    5,26    5,26    7,16    7,39    11,42   10,72   13,95
E5  0,8 0,4 1,02    1,02    1,64    1,43    1,78    1,78    1,76    1,95    2,16    1,96    3,46    2,88    4,54    3,55    7,35    8,32    10,77
E6  0,2 0,2 0,19    0,19    0,75    0,75    1,23    0,7 2,02    1,18    2,6 1,95    5,27    4,97    9,64    7,01    11,21   10,6    14,84
F1  0   0   0,2 0,2 0,2 0,2 0,21    0,41    0,2 0,41    0,59    0,79    1,99    2,19    7,59    8,64    14,29   14,01   32,27
F2  0,95    0,95    0,95    0,95    1,18    0,98    1,54    1,35    3,45    4,02    5,17    6,32    8,41    8,6 13,62   36,56   28,1    26,59   37,62
F3  0,72    0,72    0,36    0,36    0,36    0,72    1,1 1,65    2,2 2,54    3,9 4,07    6,46    7,82    11  25,09   26,67   24,67   38,85
F4  0,22    0,22    0,22    0,22    0,22    0,22    0,64    0,64    1,32    1,1 2,42    2,2 5,92    7,02    13,06   11,88   15,64   16,11   19,15
F5  0,68    0,45    1,11    1,33    0,66    0,66    0,64    1,06    1,68    1,47    2,13    2,35    2,55    3,83    5,73    6,83    9,26    9,03    12,68
F6  0   0   0   0   0,2 0,2 0,19    0,37    0,73    0,73    1,37    0,86    1,81    1,15    3,38    3,22    3,83    4,17    7,36
G1  0,47    0,47    0,44    0,44    0,41    1,43    6,69    8,72    20,4    31,59   54,26   63,65   87,72   94,39   99,82   99,12   100 100 100
G2  0,92    0,73    0,87    1,05    2,38    7,92    14,96   23,17   46,56   61,99   85,69   92,3    96,63   97,9    99,86   100 100 100 100
G3  0,59    0,59    1,03    2,23    12,42   21,24   32,92   46,08   76,8    88,02   96,04   98,33   99,4    100 100 100 100 100 100
G4  0,41    0,41    0,42    0,42    0,62    0,42    0,6 0,6 0,6 0,4 1,38    1,58    2,2 2,61    4,15    5,09    5,99    8,24    10,96
G5  0,85    0,85    1,1 1,1 0,9 0,9 1,1 1,1 1,41    1,87    1,84    2,76    4,43    3,77    6,25    7,64    9,57    10,53   11,9
G6  0,61    0,4 0,39    0,2 0,19    0   0   0,39    0,74    0,55    0,93    0,75    2,13    1,42    4,22    3,34    6,7 5,33    9,71
H1  1,62    1,62    1,54    1,85    2,11    2,11    1,97    1,97    1,78    1,78    2,48    2,75    3,18    2,92    5,61    5,61    7,33    8,38    11,87
H2  1,32    1,32    1,23    1,23    0,74    0,98    2,26    1,25    3,42    3,91    7,29    7,76    10,83   14,75   19,65   30,02   43,62   51,65   72,69
H3  0,88    0,88    0,85    0,56    0,55    0,55    0,92    0,92    1,11    1,11    1,35    2,16    3,54    4,63    10,05   15,98   28,24   37,05   46,79
H4  0,27    0,27    0,26    0   0,26    0,26    0,28    0,28    0,48    0,72    1,19    0,71    0,93    1,64    2,78    3,25    7,85    7,62    8,51
H5  0,55    0,55    0,78    0,78    0,53    0,53    0,83    0,83    0,81    0,81    1,26    1,26    1,72    1,47    4,31    3,83    5,59    5,83    8,67
H6  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0,8 0,8 1   1,25    1,96    1,22    3,25    3,02    5,97
```

The triplicates are in rows, so for example, for the case (1,1) of my "final" data frame, I want to do the means of the case of column t1, and rows A1,A2,A3.

So when I try this, i get :

> Error in avg[n, (j - 1)] : incorrect number of dimension

I tried to find the answer elsewhere, but I couldn't find something that really match to my situation. I'm really a beginner at coding so it's possible that I have a really strange way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read in the file correctly, preserving the header line as column names (`header=T`) and interpreting the number syntax (`dec=','`) then you can use `aggregate()` with a synthesized grouping column to compute the triplicate means:

```
df <- read.table('input.txt',header=T,dec=',');
aggregate(.~trip,cbind(df[-1L],trip=rep(seq_len(nrow(df)%/%3L),each=3L)),mean);
##    trip        t1          t2         t3         t4         t5         t6         t7         t8         t9       t10       t11         t12        t13        t14        t15       t16        t17        t18        t19
## 1     1 0.8833333  0.69333333  0.7500000  0.8100000  0.8566667  0.9266667  1.5566667  1.6900000  2.9766667  3.196667  6.180000   6.2566667  10.200000   9.693333  13.776667 13.796667  18.536667  19.440000  24.466667
## 2     2 1.0666667  0.71333333  1.0633333  0.9966667  1.4133333  1.4800000  1.7666667  1.7766667  2.5933333  2.590000  3.713333   3.3333333   6.430000   6.953333  11.340000 10.106667  15.710000  14.076667  20.056667
## 3     3 0.9233333  0.86666667  1.0433333  0.9900000  2.1700000  4.4266667  9.3533333 15.5466667 28.3100000 38.406667 60.133333  69.7966667  83.263333  89.703333  95.720000 97.433333  99.240000  99.733333  85.343333
## 4     4 0.1466667  0.07333333  0.2833333  0.2833333  0.5466667  1.1833333  2.6700000  3.5200000  6.1966667  7.453333 10.436667  11.2133333  17.820000  17.126667  26.020000 25.863333  32.296667  32.190000  37.850000
## 5     5 0.9133333  0.67000000  0.8633333  0.7433333  1.0133333  1.3200000  2.6366667  2.6366667  4.8866667  6.203333 10.216667  10.0100000  17.170000  14.680000  25.676667 22.036667  32.976667  28.253333  32.140000
## 6     6 0.5800000  0.51333333  0.8400000  0.5033333  3.4066667  9.7066667 29.4733333 43.2933333 70.9466667 78.713333 91.730000  93.4833333  98.683333  99.340000  99.840000 99.843333  99.946667 100.000000 100.000000
## 7     7 4.4400000 11.94333333 31.7833333 51.0000000 79.5966667 88.2566667 96.7766667 98.2800000 99.8666667 99.910000 99.956667 100.0000000 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000 99.916667 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000
## 8     8 0.6966667  0.36000000  1.0500000  1.2066667  1.7033333  2.1633333  3.2466667  4.4400000  6.7333333  8.133333 10.710000  13.1066667  17.993333  21.626667  27.683333 32.853333  39.663333  43.453333  50.413333
## 9     9 0.5133333  0.79333333  1.3533333  1.6200000  4.9400000  8.5266667 16.2866667 21.0766667 32.7966667 37.383333 47.673333  50.1933333  58.030000  58.820000  64.746667 65.506667  69.010000  69.076667  70.930000
## 10   10 0.8366667  0.63000000  0.8500000  0.8500000  1.3133333  1.1666667  1.5200000  1.2700000  2.0733333  1.856667  2.516667   2.1633333   4.663333   4.370000   7.113333  5.983333   9.993333   9.880000  13.186667
## 11   11 0.5566667  0.55666667  0.5033333  0.5033333  0.5800000  0.6333333  0.9500000  1.1366667  1.9500000  2.323333  3.220000   3.7266667   5.620000   6.203333  10.736667 23.430000  23.020000  21.756667  36.246667
## 12   12 0.3000000  0.22333333  0.4433333  0.5166667  0.3600000  0.3600000  0.4900000  0.6900000  1.2433333  1.100000  1.973333   1.8033333   3.426667   4.000000   7.390000  7.310000   9.576667   9.770000  13.063333
## 13   13 0.6600000  0.59666667  0.7800000  1.2400000  5.0700000 10.1966667 18.1900000 25.9900000 47.9200000 60.533333 78.663333  84.7600000  94.583333  97.430000  99.893333 99.706667 100.000000 100.000000 100.000000
## 14   14 0.6233333  0.55333333  0.6366667  0.5733333  0.5700000  0.4400000  0.5666667  0.6966667  0.9166667  0.940000  1.383333   1.6966667   2.920000   2.600000   4.873333  5.356667   7.420000   8.033333  10.856667
## 15   15 1.2733333  1.27333333  1.2066667  1.2133333  1.1333333  1.2133333  1.7166667  1.3800000  2.1033333  2.266667  3.706667   4.2233333   5.850000   7.433333  11.770000 17.203333  26.396667  32.360000  43.783333
## 16   16 0.2733333  0.27333333  0.3466667  0.2600000  0.2633333  0.2633333  0.3700000  0.3700000  0.4300000  0.510000  1.083333   0.9233333   1.216667   1.453333   3.016667  2.766667   5.563333   5.490000   7.716667
```

---

Regarding your error message, the problem is that you initialized `avg` to a vector (a one-dimensional data type), but then you tried to index it as a matrix (a two-dimensional data type). You could have solved the problem by initializing `avg` like this:

```
avg <- matrix(0,l0,l2);
```

But the data type issue (caused by both (1) omitting the `dec=','` argument and (2) reading in the header line as a data line) would still have been a problem anyway.

---

- [`read.table()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html)
- [`aggregate()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html)
- [`cbind()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cbind.html)
- [`seq_len()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/seq.html)
- [`rep()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rep.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your `read.table` should use `dec=","`.

Below, a solution using `dplyr` to avoid the loop (base R solutions exist):

```
# we use ',' as decimal sign, we consider the first row as header (drops it in a way), and remove the first column
data <- read.table(fileavg, header=TRUE, dec=",")[, -1]

# we load dplyr. install.packages("dplyr") if you don't have it
library(dplyr)

# The number of triplicates (be careful since some may be dropped)
nr <- floor(nrow(data)/3)

# we create a grouping variable, and average each column within each group
data %>% mutate(group=factor(rep(1:nr, each=3))) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean)) %>% 
  ungroup()

Source: local data frame [16 x 20]

group        t1          t2         t3         t4         t5         t6         t7
(fctr)     (dbl)       (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl)
1       1 0.8833333  0.69333333  0.7500000  0.8100000  0.8566667  0.9266667  1.5566667
2       2 1.0666667  0.71333333  1.0633333  0.9966667  1.4133333  1.4800000  1.7666667
3       3 0.9233333  0.86666667  1.0433333  0.9900000  2.1700000  4.4266667  9.3533333
4       4 0.1466667  0.07333333  0.2833333  0.2833333  0.5466667  1.1833333  2.6700000
5       5 0.9133333  0.67000000  0.8633333  0.7433333  1.0133333  1.3200000  2.6366667
```

Answer (score 1):

The decimal numbers in your file are separated by a comma. In order to read the data correctly this fact needs to be specified.

If `samplefile.txt` is the name of your `.txt` file, try:

```
data <- read.table("samplefile.txt", header=TRUE, dec=",")
```